# How to use Selenium with Scrapy for crawling ajax pages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Scrapy and I need to scrape a page and I'm having trouble crawling the page to be scraped.

Without filling any of the fields on the page, and clicking the "PESQUISAR" (translate: search) button directly, I need to scrape all the pages shown below.

It looks like my problem is in the page javascript .. and I've never worked with javascript.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class CarfSpider(Spider):
    name = 'carf'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Desktop/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('example.com')
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        carf = sel.xpath('//*[@id="botaoPesquisarCarf"]')
```

My main difficulty is tracking this page. So if anyone can help me with this, I appreciate it.

Sorry for the bad English, I hope you have understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use driver to click on button **Pesquisar**, call `WebDriverWait` to wait until the table element with id **tblJurisprudencia** is present indicating that page is fully loaded to get source-code, them parse **Acordão** values from the page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


class CarfSpider(Spider):

    name = 'carf'
    start_urls = ['https://carf.fazenda.gov.br/sincon/public/pages/ConsultarJurisprudencia/consultarJurisprudenciaCarf.jsf']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/laerte/chromedriver')

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        self.driver.find_element_by_id('botaoPesquisarCarf').click()

        page_loaded = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tblJurisprudencia"))
        )

        if page_loaded:
            response_selenium = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)

            table = response_selenium.xpath("//table[@id='tblJurisprudencia']")

            for row in table.xpath("//tr"):
                body = row.xpath("//div[@class='rich-panel-body ']")

                yield {
                    "acordao" : body.xpath("./a/text()").extract_first()
                }
```

Comment: you should use an "explicit wait" with an expected condition rather than a static sleep.